# How do I extend a widget.Button so that it has a new method ID in fyne?

Tags: go, user-interface, widget, extends, fyne

I did this but it doesn't work

```golang
type buttonWithID struct {
    widget.ListItemID
}

func newButtonWithID(button widget.Button) *buttonWithID {
    newButton := &buttonWithID{}
    newButton.ExtendBaseWidget(newButton)
    newButton.ListItemID = 0

    return newButton
}
```

and it returns this error:

```
newButton.ExtendBaseWidget undefined (type *buttonWithID has no field or method ExtendBaseWidget)
```

Comment: The error says, you didn't have the method `ExtendBaseWidget` for the struct `buttonWithID`. The [go tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) might help you if you're just starting out with Go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extend Button then your struct must embed the `widget.Button` type. Extra fields would be added below that.
See the tutorial at https://developer.fyne.io/tutorial/extending-widgets